# try/catch for StringIndexOutOfBoundsException not working? Java

Tags: java

my program is a recreation of the game mastermind. I am trying to protect against an error when you enter three or less characters instead of the required four, but my try/catch just... isn't doing anything. Please help‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

```
/*
 * AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
 * AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
 */
package nowornever;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author KK
 */
public class NowOrNever {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String code[] = new String[4];
        String guessNum[] = new String[4];
        String hint[] = new String[4];
        String line;
        String guess = null;
        try {//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------PREVIOUS MATCH CLEAR
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("LastMatch.txt"));
            pw.print("");
            pw.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Problem opening / writing to file");
        }
        int menu = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to read the rules? \n Enter 1 for yes or 2 for No."));
        if (menu == 1) { //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------RULES
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The object of this game is to break a number code in six turns or less.\nHow to play:\n\n1. Enter four numbers you think could be the code, from 1 to 9.\n\n2. The machine will respond by indicating whether any of your numbers are a correct guess.\n- Correct number wrong location will be indicated with a dot '•'.\n- Correct number and correct location will be indicated with a reverse dot '◘'.\n- if both number and location are wrong, there will be a blank space' '.\n\n3. Use your logic and luck to crach the code and win the game within six tries or less!\n\nIf you play again, you can find a record of your most recent match saved in 'LastMatch.txt' in the root folder of this project.");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The game is starting in the output section");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The game is starting in the output section");
        }
        try { //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------MENU PREPPER
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("LastMatch.txt", true));
            pw.println("┌─────┬─────┐");
            pw.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Problem opening / writing to file");
        }
        for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++) { //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------AI LOOP
            double randomValue = (double) (Math.random());
            if (randomValue >= 0.0 && randomValue <= 0.1111111) {
                code[count] = 1 + "";
            } else if (randomValue >= 0.1111111 && randomValue <= 0.2222222222) {
                code[count] = 2 + "";
            } else if (randomValue >= 0.2222222 && randomValue <= 0.3333333) {
                code[count] = 3 + "";
            } else if (randomValue >= 0.33333333 && randomValue <= 0.44444444) {
                code[count] = 4 + "";
            } else if (randomValue >= 0.44444444 && randomValue <= 0.555555555) {
                code[count] = 5 + "";
            } else if (randomValue >= 0.55555 && randomValue <= 0.66666666) {
                code[count] = 6 + "";
            } else if (randomValue >= 0.6666666666 && randomValue <= 0.777777777) {
                code[count] = 7 + "";
            } else if (randomValue >= 0.777777777 && randomValue <= 0.88888888) {
                code[count] = 8 + "";
            } else if (randomValue >= 0.88888888 && randomValue <= 1) {
                code[count] = 9 + "";
            } else {
                System.out.println("Issue with generating code; please try again.");
                //System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        for (int count = 0; count < 6; count++) { //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------BEGINNING OF PROCESSING LOOP

            try {//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------INPUT TRY/CATCH
                System.out.println("Please enter your guess of four numbers from 1-9. Please do not include spaces in your submission.");
                guess = input.nextLine();
            } catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException siobe){
                System.out.println("Please enter four numbers");
            }

            if (guess.contains(" ")) { //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------SPACE CHECKER
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try again, and Please do not enter spaces in between the characters.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            for (int countInternal = 0; countInternal < 4; countInternal++) { //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------TAKING GUESS APART
                guessNum[countInternal] = guess.substring(countInternal, countInternal + 1);
            }

            if (guessNum[0].equals(code[0])) {//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------CORRECT CHECKER 1
                hint[0] = "◘";
            } else if (guessNum[0].equals(code[1])) {
                hint[0] = "•";
            } else if (guessNum[0].equals(code[2])) {
                hint[0] = "•";
            } else if (guessNum[0].equals(code[3])) {
                hint[0] = "•";
            } else {
                hint[0] = " ";
            }

            if (guessNum[1].equals(code[1])) {//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------CORRECT CHECKER 2
                hint[1] = "◘";
            } else if (guessNum[1].equals(code[2])) {
                hint[1] = "•";
            } else if (guessNum[1].equals(code[3])) {
                hint[1] = "•";
            } else if (guessNum[1].equals(code[0])) {
                hint[1] = "•";
            } else {
                hint[1] = " ";
            }

            if (guessNum[2].equals(code[2])) {//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------CORRECT CHECKER 3
                hint[2] = "◘";
            } else if (guessNum[2].equals(code[3])) {
                hint[2] = "•";
            } else if (guessNum[2].equals(code[0])) {
                hint[2] = "•";
            } else if (guessNum[2].equals(code[1])) {
                hint[2] = "•";
            } else {
                hint[2] = " ";
            }

            if (guessNum[3].equals(code[3])) {//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------CORRECT CHECKER 4
                hint[3] = "◘";
            } else if (guessNum[3].equals(code[0])) {
                hint[3] = "•";
            } else if (guessNum[3].equals(code[1])) {
                hint[3] = "•";
            } else if (guessNum[3].equals(code[2])) {
                hint[3] = "•";
            } else {
                hint[3] = " ";
            }

            try {//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------PLAYER INPUT LINE PRINT
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("LastMatch.txt", true));
                pw.println("│" + guessNum[0] + guessNum[1] + guessNum[2] + guessNum[3] + "│" + hint[0] + hint[1] + hint[2] + hint[3] + "│");
                pw.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.err.println("Problem opening / writing to file");
            }

            try {//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------PLAYER INPUT LINE READ
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LastMatch.txt"));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                br.close();

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.err.println("Error reading from file");
            }
            if (guessNum[0].equals(code[0]) && guessNum[1].equals(code[1]) && guessNum[2].equals(code[2]) && guessNum[3].equals(code[3])) {//------------------------------------------------------WIN CONDITION
                count = 6;
                System.out.println("You Win!");
            }
        } //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------END OF ENTERING AND PRCESSING LOOP
        System.out.println("Game Over!");
        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("LastMatch.txt", true));
            pw.println("└─────┴─────┘");
            pw.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Problem opening / writing to file");
        }
        System.out.println("Final Game Board:");
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LastMatch.txt"));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            br.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Error reading from file");
        }
        try {//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------PLAYER INPUT LINE PRINT
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("LastMatch.txt", true));
                pw.println("The code was:" + code[0] + code[1] + code[2] + code[3]);
                pw.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.err.println("Problem opening / writing to file");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error, which will typically tell you exactly where the error occurred, and why. Note that this line `input.nextLine()` which you are trying to catch will never throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, rather the error is caused by using `substring` with an out of bounds index. To make the exception work you need to wrap the entire code block including the substring code inside the `try` bracers

Answer (score 0):

`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs when you try to access the character index which doesn't exists. e.g. String length is 3 and you are trying to access str.charAt(4) etc.
In your program, (which I believe isn't having the most optimum solution but respecting your logic),  should handle it at below lines and not while taking input from user.

```
try {
   guessNum[countInternal] = guess.substring(countInternal, countInternal + 1);
} catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException siobe){
   System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Better solution would be, while taking the input, check length of a string

```
while(true) {
   System.out.println("Please enter your guess of four numbers from 1-9. Please do not include spaces in your submission.");
   guess = input.nextLine();
   if(guess.length()==4) {
       break;
   }else{
       System.out.println("Please enter four numbers");
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line that is currently wrapped inside your `try` block is `guess = input.nextLine();` which will never throw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, rather the error is caused by using substring with an out of bounds index here `guess.substring(countInternal, countInternal + 1);`.

To make the exception work correctly you need to wrap the entire code block including the substring code inside the try bracers like the following, however, we also need to use a while loop to get the inputs if the exception is caught:

```
//We need to wrap any code that can have multiple attempts inside a while loop

//Variable to control the while loop
boolean waiting = true;
//Loop to get 4 inputs
while (waiting)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter your guess of four numbers from 1-9. Please do not include spaces in your submission.");
        guess = input.nextLine();
        //Remove any spaces in the guess
        guess = guess.replaceAll(" ", "");

    try {
        //Process the input INSIDE the try block
        for (int countInternal = 0; countInternal < 4; countInternal++) {
            guessNum[countInternal] = guess.substring(countInternal, countInternal + 1);
        }
        //Success, if the code reached here then no errors were thrown, and we can change the flag so that the loop stops after this cycle
        waiting = false;
    }
    catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException siobe){
        System.out.println("Please enter four numbers");
        //Move to the next loop cycle and skip all code below
        continue;
    }
}

//Put code here to be done after storing the 4 inputs in guessNum
//...
```

However, the above is not a good solution, we should never rely on a `try/catch` block to run our code, rather we should work with absolute values. For example, we can use an `if` statement inside a while loop to check the length of the input. As before we need to wrap any code that can have multiple attempts inside a while loop:

```
//Variable to control the while loop
boolean waiting = true;
//Loop to get 4 inputs
while (waiting)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter your guess of four numbers from 1-9. Please do not include spaces in your submission.");
        guess = input.nextLine();
        //Remove any spaces in the guess
        guess = guess.replaceAll(" ", "");
    
    if(guess.length() < 4)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter four numbers");
        //Do this: Move to the next loop cycle and skip all code below
        continue;
    }
    //Or do this: Put any following code in an else block so that it is not exected unless the length is over 4
    else {
        //Success, change the flag so that the loop stops after this cycle
        waiting = false;
        //Process the input
        for (int countInternal = 0; countInternal < 4; countInternal++) {
            guessNum[countInternal] = guess.substring(countInternal, countInternal + 1);
        }
    }
}

//Put code here to be done after storing the 4 inputs in guessNum
//...
```